# SQL Express 2005/2008 Concurrent Connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

How many concurrent connections do the express editions allow?

My front end uses standard ADO.Net code where I open the connection to the server, get my data, and then close the connection.  Am I right in saying that as soon as the connection is closed, it then allows this connection to be opened by another user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The express editions of SQL Server don't cap the number of concurrent connections - they exert limitations in other ways - such as the maximum size of the database (4GB), CPU sockets (1) and amount of memory (1GB).

More info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx).

You are right in saying that when a connection is closed, its resources are released immediately. The only caveat on this is connection pooling in .NET.

Comment: connection pooling means that you can server multiple web requests from different users without having to bring up & tear down individual SQL Server connections. This is a good thing!

Comment: @Joe Albahari - link doesn't seem to go to the right page anymore

Answer (score 1):

.net handles all of that for you. It creates a connection pool per unique connection string and your DB calls will share the connection. .Net does not really open/close real connections when you call conn.Open() , the connection pooling handles that.